# fastboot cannot see my phone (moto3g) when adb can

Tags: adb, fastboot

**Introduction:**

My phone is [moto3g](https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-g-gen-3) (bootloader unlocked), my OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) and I want to install Debian native on it. To do so, I need root my device, and to do it i have to use fastboot and adb command.

**What doesn't work:**

`fastboot devices` shows nothing, other fastboot commands shows `<waiting for any device>` (adb works good, as excepted).

**Things that I did**

-Turn on usb debugging.
-running fastboot with sudo
-run one of fastboot commands ADB `adb reboot recovery`
-run one of fastboot commands when android was booted
-installed some drivers with those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libz1 libncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6 libbz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libcurl4-gnutls-dev:i386
```

-my andoird rules (`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2e76", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

I tried 2 versions of idVendor: "2e76" (from `lsusb`) and "22b8" from [this site](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/guide-installing-adb-fastboot-linux-adb-t3478678).

Had someone of you similiar issue? I think its something with drivers, but I couldn't find that myself.

PS. I have also windows machine, so I can use it if needed.

EDIT: I wasn't rebooting between doing those things.

Comment: Fastboot will not work within recovery. When in recovery you are not within the bootloader were fastboot works. Adb works within the Android OS or within recovery.  Try `adb reboot bootloader` then enter the command `fastboot devices`

Comment: your solution did work for me. try sudo fastboot, or double check fastboot from windows (maybe phone have problem)

Comment: @alecxs I edited my answer, I did both of things that you wrote

Comment: @BoLawson I edited my answer, I did both of things that you wrote

Comment: how did you unlock bootloader then? check with another device / cable

Comment: I followed steps from motorola unlocking support - and fastboot there was working well, as excepted @alecxs